# Is there a way to format the email display?

Tags: php, html-email

All the information are from a form. when submit the form, I use php `mail()` to send all the information to my email box, but I don't know how to format all the informatioin which from the submitted form.

is there a way to format the email which displays as the following style.

[image]

if using `mail()` can get that,how do i do? or there is another way to get that, thank you.

Comment: on submit the values and image are sent to database?

Comment: no,i want to send the information to my email box

Answer (score 2):

Don't use mail().

Instead use the phpmailer class.
http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.phpmailer.php
http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

You call the class in your code.

```
require "includes/class.phpmailer.php";
```

Then you format your mail strings using HTML and a bit of common sense.  To format the way you want you can use p and line breaks.  Images, links, most of what you would think to use in html.  It has worked well for me.

Tip:  You don't want to include external css so your html might have to be a bit old school with text-align and setting width in using style.

edited.
call the include

```
require "includes/class.phpmailer.php";
```

then, set a few variables such as your message ... do your formatting.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddReplyTo($emailAddress, "Your Reply Name");  // could be $replayemail if set
$mail->AddAddress($mailto);                           // who you are emailing  
$mail->SetFrom($emailAddress, "Your From Name");      // from email
$mail->Subject = $subject;                            // keep it simple, email header
$mail->MsgHTML($message);                             // format fun stuff in $message 
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: thank、 you but i don't know how to use it. if i couldn't do $mail->IsSMTP();  could i send the email thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about PHP HTML mail.

IMO best school for PHP beginners: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 0):

Set the headers like this

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

This would allow you to send html in mail.You can apply styling too.